# Distance from the camera to an object.. Error correction

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

I'm estimating the distance from camera to a chessboard. However, the error is increasing linearly as long as I get far from the pattern. 
Is that normal? How can I correct that error?

I corrected that error using a simple linear equation and it works but it doesn't depend on camera parameter as I believe it should be, so the correction will be robust:
error = 72.51+distNorme*0.0278;

I compute the distance from the Chessboard using OpenCV and my camera parameters following those steps:

1- findChessboardCorners

2- solvePnP

3- ->Distance from the translation vector given by solvePnP

I'll be also interested in correcting the rotation and the translation errors later on when I'll have better pattern for tracking

Answer (score 0):

I'll write an answer to the issue after doing some experiments. I corrected my distance as follow:

```
Distance_corrected = distNorme+distNorme*correction
```

`distNorme` is the distance to the chessboard which is the norm of the translation vector given by `solvePnP` OpenCV function.

`correction` is

```
correction=pixel_size/focal_mm/2 = 2/focal_pixel
```

The results are better, still have an error increasing linearly though but not very strong as `distNorme` (distance not corrected).

I'm still seeking for references or documentation of that `correction` error. I need more details about it.